# How can I run android-testify tests with Dagger Hilt?

Tags: android, junit, dagger-hilt, screenshot-testing, android-testify

I am attempting to integrate https://github.com/Shopify/android-testify to add screenshot testing to my app. I am having trouble, however, with getting the simplest of tests to run due to my app's current integration with Dagger Hilt.

If I try to add only the ScreenshotRule as suggested by Testify's documentation, I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.
```

Additionally, if I use both the standard hilt rule (`HiltAndroidRule(this)`) alongside the ScreenshotRule, the tests just fail immediately, including tests that worked before adding the ScreenshotRule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any first-hand experience with Hilt and Testify, but I do have some experience with mixing multiple test `Rule` instances together. The issue there is that each rule assumes that it's going to be the only test rule running in a given test class. So, declaring multiple `Rule` instances can have them compete with one another and leave them in a state where they just fail immediately.

In order to get the rules to work together, you may need to use a `ruleChain`.

https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html

This article on developer.android.com demonstrates a couple of techniques for dealing with multiple `TestRule` objects in your tests:
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#multiple-testrules

Comment: Thank you! That ended up doing the trick for me. For the next person, the rules looked like this: `@get:Rule(order = 0) val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
@get:Rule(order = 1) var screenshotRule = ScreenshotRule(MyActivity::class.java)`